# How do I capture a price with thousand and decimal separator with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, matching, python-re

I currently have a code working but the only flaw is that I did'nt set the regex python code in the optimal way.

The original text contains an amount in thousands hundred thousands and millions. With no decimal. I mean it has decimal but always ",00".

Example line in Text:

> Debt 1 of 2 for an amount of: $ 58.610,00, Unpaid

Right now with the following code is capturing millions fine but less than 100,000 is skipping one digit.

```
regex = r"(\d+).(\d+).(\d+),(\d+)"
            match = re.search(regex, line, re.MULTILINE)
            print = "$"+match.group(1)+match.group(2)+match.group(3)
```

It captures like this:

> $5860

But target is like this:

> $58610

If the amount is in millions it captures fine, I had to do it like that because the currency that I'm working with it has big amounts. So I constantly manage those kind of quantities.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to extract your expected matches and remove the thousand separator afterwards:

```py
\$\s?(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?(?!\d)
```

You need to get Group 1 value,  remove periods from it and reappend `$` at the start. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q1scjV/5). *Details*:

- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)` - Group 1: one to three digits, and then one or more occurrences (since you only want to match thousands and more) of `.` and three digits
- `(?:,\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a comma and one or more digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit is allowed immediately on the right.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XEDboE):

```py
import re
text = 'Debt 1 of 2 for an amount of: $ 58.610,00, Unpaid'
match = re.search(r'\$\s?(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?(?!\d)', text)
if match:
    print(f"${match.group(1).replace('.', '')}")

# => $58610
```

Comment: You're the man! This works Perfect! Thank you very much. I appreciate it